# Undefined variable: post in

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, undefined

I'm debugging my wordpress theme and I keep getting this notification in my functions.php file:

Undefined variable: post in (myfolders)/functions.php on line 961

This is line 961

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mpc_projects_description', true));
```

The code is for a custom tinymce for my custom post type(Portfolio) project description.

What is causing variable to be undefined? Here is the code in it's entirety:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'mpc_add_description_meta_box' );
// Add the projects Meta Box
function mpc_add_description_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box('mpc_add_description_meta_box', 'Project Description', 'mpc_add_description_meta_box_callback', 'portfolio', 'normal', 'high');
}

// the description output
function mpc_add_description_meta_box_callback() {
    global $post;
    // Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="mpc_projects_description_noncename" id="mpc_projects_description_noncename" value="'.wp_create_nonce(plugin_basename(__FILE__)).'" />';
    // Get the location data if its already been entered
    $input = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mpc_projects_description', true);
   // echo '<input type="text" name="mpc_projects_description" value="' . $input  . '" "  />';
    wp_editor($input, 'mpc_projects_description', array('textarea_name' => 'mpc_projects_description', 'editor_css' => '<style>#wp-mpc_projects_description-editor-container{background-color:white;style="width:100%;}</style>'));

    echo '<table id="post-status-info" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td id="wp-word-count">Word count: <span class="word-count_2">';
    $words = strip_tags($input);
    $count = str_word_count($words, 0);
    echo $count;
    echo '</span></td>
    <td class="autosave-info">
    <span class="autosave-message">&nbsp;</span>
    </td>
    </tr></tbody></table>';
}

//save the data
add_action('save_post', 'mpc_save_description_meta', 1, 2); // save the custom fields
function mpc_save_description_meta($post_id, $post) {
    // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
    // because save_post can be triggered at other times
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['mpc_projects_description_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
    return $post->ID;
    }
    // Is the user allowed to edit the post or page?
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ))
        return $post->ID;
    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
    // We'll put it into an array to make it easier to loop though.
    $mpc_description_meta['mpc_projects_description'] = $_POST['mpc_projects_description'];
    // Add values of $mpc_description_meta as custom fields
    foreach ($mpc_description_meta as $key => $value) { // Cycle through the $mpc_description_meta array!
        if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return; // Don't store custom data twice
        $value = implode(',', (array)$value); // If $value is an array, make it a CSV (unlikely)
        if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) { // If the custom field already has a value
            update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
        } else { // If the custom field doesn't have a value
            add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
        }
        if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key); // Delete if blank
    }
}



echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mpc_projects_description', true));
```

Comment: Where you are using `get_post_meta($post->ID`, The variable `$post` does not have anything in it (like an ID).  You need to see if you can find where that's supposed to be being set.  There is probably an error in there.  For instance, if it is being set for users who are logged in, but not being set for users who are not logged in.  Something like that.

Comment: I'm sorry @Quixrick but I don't understand when you say the variable $post does not have anything in it. Do I need to replace "ID" with something.

Comment: No.  The error you are getting is because you are trying to pass `$post->ID` as a parameter.  The only thing is that you do not have `$post->ID` set, so it's throwing the error because you are trying to pass it something that doesn't exist.  `$post` should have things in it, like an `ID` for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post global is available inside the functions but you haven't set it outside.

Change:

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mpc_projects_description', true));
```

To:

```
global $post;
echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mpc_projects_description', true));
```

This could also depend on where you use this code. If you fire the code before the post object is set then you'll get this error.

If it's just in functions.php then change it to:

```
function wpse_post_test() {
    global $post;
    echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mpc_projects_description', true));
}
add_action( 'wp', 'wpse_post_test' );
```

After reviewing your question again it appears you are attempting to output this inside functions.php. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Nathan. Yes, I have this code in my functions.php file. I have a custom post type called Portfolio and for each post I'm trying to create an extra tinymce for my project descriptons.

Comment: I tried your second solution and it got rid of the Undefined variable but it places my content that I added to the tinymce in the area where I call it on the page but also at the top of the screen.

Comment: What were you expecting to happen when you inserted this into functions.php? If it was shown in the correct area as well as at the top of the screen delete that new function entirely and problem solved.